# AJAX function call within Joomla Component

Tags: php, ajax, url, joomla

I have a good understanding of AJAX and normally would have no problems using it but I am relatively new to Joomla and have only recently started building components, etc.

I have created a component (named directory) which is using the 'default' view. Within here I have the following code which is an AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
var url = "index.php?option=com_directory&view=directory&task=clubFilter&format=raw";
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#city').change(function() {         

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: jQuery("#city").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('data');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And within my 'views/directory/views.html' file I have created the following function which currently contains a die so I can confirm when it is working:

```
public function clubFilter() {
        die(print_r('here_i_am'));
    }
```

When I run the following code I ge the following error within Firebugs console..

```
'Error: 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: directory, raw, directoryView'
```

I think it is because of the AJAX url var being incorrect but I have tried many different solutions from here nad other sources and just can't get the AJAX function working. Is my URL wrong?
Many Thanks

Comment: this tutorial will also be helpful: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_AJAX_to_your_component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, I make ajax calls to a task on the controller.

Here is the url format I am using in one of my extensions that uses ajax calls to a component:

```
index.php?format=raw&option=<component_name_goes_here>&task=<task_goes_here>
```

Then, in my component's default controller I put a function with the same name as the task:

```
function getSomeData()
{
   echo(json_encode($data));//I normally return json
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi #. Thanks for your help. Unfortuntely that hasn't solved the issue. It still sayd that it can't load the view which is bizarre as it's a controller I'm trying to load!

Comment: What url is it trying to load?

Comment: This is the exact URL shown in firebug console when I click the link which starts the AJAX call. index.php?format=raw&option=com_directory&task=clubFilter

Comment: The url looks fine. Is the task function in the default controller for the com_directory component?

Comment: That's solved it!! Thanks... I put the function in the 'controller.php' file as that was my default controller and it worked. I had put the file in a different controller which was not being used. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just as an extra tip, if you want to call a function in another controller use task=controller_name.function_name

Answer (score 3):

try this url. it might help you out.

```
var url = "index.php?option=com_directory&view=directory&task=clubFilter&tmpl=component";
```

`format=raw` replace with `&tmpl=component`

Else you can try the below format too.

```
jQuery.post('index.php',{
                        'option':'component_name',
                        'controller':'controller_name',
                        'task':'task_name',
                        'format':'raw',                   
                        'data': jQuery("#city").serialize(),
                        'dataType': 'json',
                },function(result){                     
                      //edit the result here

                    return;
       });
```

If you have any problem regarding this don't hesitate to ask.